# Guess The Number Game Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am making a guess the number game however my code is not running on Atom. It does not allow me to use inputs for some reason.-
Here is my code:

```
import time
import random
again = 'yes'
print('Loading please wait... ')
time.sleep(2)
print('Hello and welcome to Guessmania!')
name = input('To start please enter your name: ')
name = name.capitalize()
time.sleep(1)
print('Hello ' + name + ', In this game I will choose a number between 1 and 20 and you must guess it in 5 attempts. ')
time.sleep(3)
print('With me telling you whether your guess is too high or too low.')
while again == 'yes' or again =='Y' or again == 'Yes':
    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    guessesFinished = 0
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Are you Ready?')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Well, ' + name + ', I am guessing a number between 1 and 20. ')
    time.sleep(1)
    for guessesFinished in range(5): #5 guesses to get it right
        guess = int(input('Have a guess: '))
        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.')
        if guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')
        if guess == number:
            break
    if guess == number:
        guessesFinished = str(guessesFinished + 1)
        print('Great work ' + name + '! You guessed the number I chose in ' + guessesFinished + ' guesses!')#Shows that user has won or lost
    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print('Sorry. The number I was chose was ' + number + '.')
    again = input('Would you like to play the Guess the Number Game again? ')#asking user if they want to play again
print('Thank you for playing. Have a good day.')
```

I have used this code but it is not accepting any inputs when I run it.

Comment: I believe Atom is just a text editor? Your code accepts input when I run it

Comment: Try running your code from the command line and see what happens

Comment: Oh, when I try it in Atom to run it it doen't work but with package listed below it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another package. I tried using a package but that did not work. Use this package to run the code instead. It is called atom-python-run. Here is the Github link-https://github.com/foreshadow/atom-python-run